# .Net Core Memory Usage

Tags: .net, .net-core, openxml, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-framework-version

I have a simple console application where it read the flat file and convert them into excel. To convert  flat file into excel I am using Open-XML SAX approach. I ran the code in both .net framework 4.7.2 and .net core 3.1 in 32 bit. In .net framework I am converting the 1300 MB file into excel using only 300 MB memory, while on .net core 3.1 I try to convert 200 MB flat file it throws me Memory Exception error.

Note: I have requirement to run my application on 32 bit.

For exact same code, why .net core throwing memory exception? Does .net core have some issue on memory usage?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a change in `System.Package` between .NET Framework and .NET Core.  It's a known issue, I was able to cobble together a workaround (with limitations) based off of some suggestions from Microsoft.  On GitHub they indicated that opening the `Package` in `Write` and not `ReadWrite` mode would allow for a large spreadsheet to be streamed with the SAX approach.  Because of this approach, *the order is important*.  The first thing you write out in `Write` mode has to be the large sheet because any other `OpenXmlWriter` instances that are opened will require `ReadWrite` or they'll throw an exception (thus the limitation).

Here's the steps I followed:

1. Create a `FileStream` (I used `File.Create`).
2. Create a `Package`, pass in the `FileStream` and use `FileMode.Create` and `FileAccess.Write`
3. Create a `SpreadsheetDocument` via `SpreadsheetDocument.Create`
4. Write your large `WorksheetPart` via an `OpenXmlWriter`
5. Close and Dispose of the writer, the package, the file stream, etc.
6. Create a `FileStream` (open this time, `File.Open` with `FileMode.Open`, `FileAccess.ReadWrite` and `FileShare.None`)
7. Create a `Package`, pass in the `FileStream` and use `FileMode.Open` and `FileAccess.ReadWrite`
8. Create a `SpreadsheetDocument` via `SpreadsheetDocument.Open`
9. Create an `OpenXmlWriter` for the `WorkbookPart` and add the elements for `Workbook` and `Sheets`, then you'll associate the `Sheet` you added on the original create, close and dispose of those objects and done.

Now, some example code that should get you close.  I'm writing an `IDataReader` out to the sheet here.  There are a few string extensions I didn't include here but you can just remove or change to fit your needs.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class ExcelDoc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a single sheet spreadsheet from an <see cref="IDataReader"/> that is capable of writing large
    /// quantities of data with a low memory footprint on .NET Core.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dr"></param>
    /// <param name="workSheetName"></param>
    public static void ToFile(string outputFileName, IDataReader dr, string workSheetName)
    {
        string worksheetPartId;

        // Create a file with write access.  To write the large dataset it must first thing written
        // to the writer, any subsequent OpenXmlWriter's seem to require a read.  Because of this, it
        // limits us to one large dataset on one sheet.
        using (var fs = File.Create(outputFileName))
        {
            using (var package = Package.Open(fs, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (var excel = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(package, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    // Create the Workbook for the spreadsheet
                    excel.AddWorkbookPart();

                    // Create the writer that we're going to use.. it will write data into the parts of the spreadsheet
                    // which we will then write into the Spreadsheet.
                    List<OpenXmlAttribute> oxa;

                    var wsp = excel.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(wsp);

                    // We need to get the part ID that we'll larger use to associate the sheet we create to this data.
                    worksheetPartId = excel.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsp);

                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                    // Header Row
                    int index = 1;

                    oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                    // this is the row index
                    oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", null, index.ToString()));

                    // This is for the row
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row(), oxa);

                    for (int x = 0; x <= dr.FieldCount - 1; x++)
                    {
                        var cell = GetCell(typeof(string), dr.GetName(x));
                        oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));
                        oxw.WriteElement(cell);
                    }

                    // This is for the row
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();

                    // Add a row for each data item.
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        index += 1;

                        oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();

                        // this is the row index
                        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", null, index.ToString()));

                        // This is for the row
                        oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row(), oxa);

                        // Add value for each field in the DataReader.
                        for (int x = 0; x <= dr.FieldCount - 1; x++)
                        {
                            var cell = GetCell(dr[x].GetType(), dr[x].ToString());
                            oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                            oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));
                            oxw.WriteElement(cell);
                        }

                        // this is for Row
                        oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    }

                    // this is for SheetData
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();

                    // this is for Worksheet
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    oxw.Close();
                    oxw.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        // Phase 2, we've already written our large dataset, now we need to add the workbook, the sheets and
        // associate the dataset to a sheet.  This requires ReadWrite, it won't be a memory issue because this
        // part doesn't take much memory.
        using (var fs = File.Open(outputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (var package = Package.Open(fs, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var excel = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(package))
                {
                    // Create the writer that will handle the outer portion of the spreadsheet, it will need to have
                    // these tags closed out when the spreadsheet is closed.
                    var oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(excel.WorkbookPart);
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Workbook());
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Sheets());

                    // Writer this into the global Writer we have open.
                    oxw.WriteElement(new Sheet()
                    {
                        Name = $"{workSheetName}",
                        SheetId = 1,
                        Id = worksheetPartId
                    });

                    // this is for Sheets
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();

                    // this is for Workbook
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    oxw.Close();
                    oxw.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a spreadsheet <see cref="Cell"/> with its type set according to the .NET type of the data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <param name="value">The CellValue for the returned <see cref="Cell"/></param>
    private static Cell GetCell(Type type, string value)
    {
        var cell = new Cell();

        if (type.ToString() == "System.RuntimeType")
        {
            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.SafeLeft(32767));
            return cell;
        }

        if (type.ToString() == "System.Guid")
        {
            Guid guidResult;
            Guid.TryParse(value, out guidResult);
            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(guidResult.ToString());
            return cell;
        }

        // Make sure the value isn't null before putting it into the cell.
        // If it is null, put a blank in the cell.
        if (value == null || Convert.IsDBNull(value))
        {
            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue("");
            return cell;
        }

        var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(type);

        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.String:
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;

                // `ToValidXmlAsciiCharacters` will remove any invalid XML characters falling in the ascii code range of 0-32
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.SafeLeft(32767).ToValidXmlAsciiCharacters());
                break;

            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.Int32:
            case TypeCode.Int64:
            case TypeCode.Double:
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
            case TypeCode.Single:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                // Second most common cases
                cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
                break;

            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(value).Date;
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue($"{dt.Year}/{dt.MonthTwoCharacters()}/{dt.DayTwoCharacters()}");
                break;
            default:
                // Everything else
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
                break;
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn't ideal but but it will get you one large sheet without getting the out of memory exception.  I tested this .NET 5 but it should work with 3.1 as well.

I'm including the GitHub issue on the OpenXml library and also the dotnet runtime issue where this is discussed and I got the idea for the workaround.

- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/807
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1544

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is looking to make a huge difference in our use case (1.5GB memory consumption vs 25MB). AddWorkbookPart was throwing an exception for us ("Cannot retrieve parts of writeonly container") until we updated our `System.IO.Packaging` NuGet package, but now I think we're on our way to success.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that, I can see that being a frustrating thing to troubleshoot since that bit of code is out of our reach.  I'm probably going to have to use this solution in a month or two myself, but what you experienced reminds me of how fragile it is (any bit that forces a read will cause it fail, whether it's us reading or something internal).  Glad to hear you got it working / it works for you. :)

Comment: @b.pell I have followed your example using .net core 3.1 and I find that memory impact is still high. I user Dapper to populate the dataset `var rows = data.Select(x => (IDictionary<string, object>)x).ToList();` which returns 325K rows and 13 columns. When debugging in Visual Studio after phase 1 completes memory has increased by 1GB and never retreats even after phase 2 completes. I thought the benefit to this SAX approach and writing the file to disk help reduce impact memory. The resulting Excel file is only 18MB in size. Do you have any other pointers that might help? Thanks

Comment: @OjM My first thought is, once you call "ToList()" I believe it fully realizes that list into memory (as opposed to not calling ToList and iterating over the IEnumerable and appending to the sheet in the loop).

Comment: @b.pell I changed to a foreach loop and used the IEnumerable result from Dapper instead but memory still climbs very high as the loop which writes the data is executing. Also I had to add `oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);` and `oxw.WriteEndElement();` before/after each cell write statement which I assume is missing from your example above?